# Variable not updated in compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, mutablestateof

I have a class in Kotlin (Jetpack compose) with a variable *title* and an exoplayer that updates the *title*.

```
class Player{
var title by mutableStatOf("value")
....

title= "new value"
...
}

@Composable
fun Display(){
val player = Player()

player.title?.let{
Text(it)
} 
}
```

In the user interface an instance of the class is created and the title displayed but it remains unchanged after being updated in the class. Can someone help?

Comment: please provide some more detail to answer your question

Comment: Can you elaborate? The problem  is: A mutablestate variable is updated within a class and the updated value does not update in the Composable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to `remember` the player instance. Here, when you change `title`, your composable is recomposed because it reads the title. But when it is recomposed, you create new instance of `Player` with the default title.

```
val player = remember { Player() }
```

Comment: You are right and thanks for the answer. But if I start the player to update the title from a broadcast receiver the title value is updated but the update does not reach the user interface. Is that fixable?

Comment: You can't access Player instance that you created in your composable from Broadcast receiver, that's not possible. Like I said in the other question, you can for example have singleton of Player created in your application class or managed with some dependency injection framework and access that both from compose and broadcast receiver.